# Limiting the npm react-date-picker to show only last 30 days from today dynamically in react

Tags: reactjs, date, npm, jsx, react-datepicker

Show only last 30 days from today in npm react-date-picker dynamically in react.
Future dates from tomorrow should be disabled.

```
import DatePicker from "react-date-picker";
<DatePicker maxDate={new Date()} />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What exactly is the question? You can create a date 30 days from now in JavaScript as follows:

```
var futureDate = new Date();
futureDate.setDate(futureDate.getDate() + 30);
```

Comment: Actually, my datepicker shows dates till previous 10 years, I want to limit it to show only for the last 1 month(30 days).

Comment: import DatePicker from "react-date-picker";
<DatePicker minDate={futureDate} maxDate={new Date()} />

Comment: Then call the variable `minDate` and replace `+ 30` with `-30`.
`<DatePicker minDate={minDate} ... />` should work.

Answer (score 1):

```
maxDate={new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 90)}
```

Future date disable in react js. Here from today 90 days will be available for selecting

Answer (score 0):

you can use moment() and especially the function subtract()
like in the exemple:

```
<DatePicker maxDate={new Date()}

 minDate={moment(new Date()).subtract(30, 'days')} />
```